# Grep inside while loop removes the file!! [Bash script]

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep

I'm working writing a bash script and I am becoming crazy with a mysterious loop... so I'm asking to you expecting someone could give some help.

I need to seek for a concrete code inside a text file (codigos.txt) that contains many codes and, if the code is found, I need to seek for the next one (siguienteCodigo++) until the code is not found, so I've written the next while loop (where $siguienteCodigo is the variable containing the code to search and $rutaOrigen is the path to the file containing the codes, codigos.txt):

```
while grep -F "$siguienteCodigo" "$rutaOrigen/codigos.txt"; do
    let siguienteCodigo++
done
```

But when I execute the script, my surprise is that it seems to find the codes but the codigos.txt file is removed! Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Below is the complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
################################################################################
# SCRIPT PARA CODIFICAR RECURSIVAMENTE TODAS LAS FOTOGRAFÍAS DE LOS ARTÍCULOS  #
# Y REGISTRARLAS EN UNA HOJA DE CÁLCULO DE MICROSOFT EXCEL                     #
################################################################################
#
# Extraemos el día, mes, año, hora, minuto y segundo
day="$(date +%d)"
month="$(date +%m)"
year="$(date +%Y)"
hour="$(date +%H)"
minute="$(date +%M)"
second="$(date +%S)"
# Extraemos la ruta de origen, donde se ejecuta el script
rutaOrigen="$(pwd)"
# Recorremos todos los directorios listados recursivamente, a partir de la ruta
# de origen
for d in $(ls -R | grep "^\." | sed 's/://'); do
    # Cambiamos al directorio
    cd "$d"
    # Buscamos cuál es el último artículo codificado
    ultimoCodigo=$(printf "%08d" "0")
    # Recorremos todos los archivos que nos interesa listar, que son todos
    # los archivos con extensión .jpg .JPG y .txt
    for i in $(ls *.jpg *.JPG *.txt); do
        # Extraemos el nombre del archivo, sin extensión
        case "${i##*.}" in
            "jpg")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".jpg" "$i")";;
            "JPG")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".JPG" "$i")";;
            "txt")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".txt" "$i")";;
        esac
        # Extraemos los 8 primeros carácteres del archivo, que
        # corresponderán al "código 8" del artículo
        codigo8=$(expr substr "$fotoActual" 1 8)
        # Si los 8 primeros carácteres del archivo forman un numérico
        # entero y éste es mayor que el último "codigo 8" guardado,
        # inicialmente iniciado a 0...
        if [[ $codigo8 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && (( codigo8 > ultimoCodigo )); then
            # Guardamos el "código 8" actual como el último código,
            # es decir, como el último artículo codificado
            ultimoCodigo=$(printf "%08d" "$codigo8")
        fi
    done
    # Volvemos a recorrer todos los archivos que nos interesa listar, esta
    # vez para codificar los que no están codificados, es decir, los que
    # siguen al último artículo codificado
    for i in $(ls *.jpg *.JPG *.txt); do
        # Extraemos el nombre del archivo, sin extensión
        case "${i##*.}" in
            "jpg")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".jpg" "$i")";;
            "JPG")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".JPG" "$i")";;
            "txt")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".txt" "$i")";;
        esac
        # Extraemos los 8 primeros carácteres del archivo, que
        # corresponderán al "código 8" del artículo
        codigo8=$(expr substr "$fotoActual" 1 8)
        siguienteCodigo=$(($ultimoCodigo + 1))
        # Si los 8 primeros carácteres del archivo forman un numérico
        # entero y éste es mayor que el último "código 8" guardado...
        if [[ $codigo8 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && (( codigo8 <= ultimoCodigo )); then
            :
        else
            while grep -F "$siguienteCodigo" "$rutaOrigen/codigos.txt"; do
                let siguienteCodigo++
            done
            rutaActual="$(pwd)"
            carpetaActual="$(basename "$rutaActual")"
            caracteresCarpeta=$(expr length "$carpetaActual")
            descripcion="$(expr substr "$carpetaActual" 10 $caracteresCarpeta)"
            rutaActual="$(echo -e "$rutaActual" | sed 's/\//\\/g' | sed 's/\\media\\sf_E_DRIVE/E:/')"
            let ultimoCodigo++
            newFile=$(printf "%08d_${day}-${month}-${year}_${hour}-${minute}-${second}.jpg" "$siguienteCodigo")
            mv -- "$i" "$newFile"
            echo -e "$siguienteCodigo\t$rutaActual\t$descripcion\t$day/$month/$year\t$hour:$minute:$second" | awk -F '\t' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' OFS='\t' >> "$rutaOrigen/registroarticulos.xls"
        fi
    done
    cd "$rutaOrigen"
done
echo "Se creó una hoja de registro en $rutaOrigen/registroarticulos.xls"
echo "Todas las fotografías fueron codificadas correctamente :)"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid **parent directory** with:

```
ls -R | grep "^\./" | sed 's/://'
```

`codigos.txt` is *entering* the second `for` loop.

Alternativaly change the file extension or use a `continue` statement if `${i##*.}` equals to `codigos`.

**NOTE**: This flow could be redone without parsing avoiding grep usage.

Comment: Much better advice would be to avoid parsing ls entirely :)

Comment: You're completily right ! @TomFenech the script could be redone in a much more propper way ..no doubt about it..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, klashxx :) The problem is that I need to seek recursively inside all directories from a parent directory, included the parent directory. Maybe a solution would be moving codigos.txt into a upper directory and grepping directly to it.

Comment: And what would be the solution to seek inside all directories without parsing ls, Tom Fenech?

Comment: Or just change codigos file extension @kalero

Comment: That's another solution. Thanks @klashxx :)